# Problem in importing Fortran module in a Python Package in Github actions

Tags: python, fortran, github-actions, f2py

To speed up a part of code in a Python package, I wrote a Fortran subroutine. It works ok on my local system. Here is the package structure.

```
p_name/
        setup.py
        p_name/
               __init__.py
              fortran_sc_folder/
                               rsp.f95
```

Here is the (part of) setup.py:

```py
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
ext1 = Extension(name='p_name.fortran_sc_folder.rsp', sources=['p_name/fortran_sc_folder/rsp.f95']) 

setup(
...
ext_modules = [ext1]
...
)
```

Inside the program, I use the following to access the module:

```py
import .fortran_sc_folder.rsp
```

It installs and works without raising any error. However, when I push the changes, it cannot pass the GitHub actions. The error is:

```py
E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p_name.fortran_cs_folder.rsp'
```

Do you know how to fix this, and is there any better way to use a Fortran code inside a python package?

Update:
Here is the GitHub action workflow:

```yaml
# This workflow will install Python dependencies, run tests and lint with a variety of Python versions
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-python-with-github-actions

name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, develop ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7, 3.8]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Setup conda
      uses: s-weigand/setup-conda@v1
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
        conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
        
    # - name: Lint with flake8
    #   run: |
    #     # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
    #     flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
    #     # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
    #     flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
```

Comment: Could you post the GitHub Actions workflow file as well?

Comment: @RossMacArthur, thanks. I updated the thread and added the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @RossMacArthur 's comment/question I realized that the package on GitHub action is the code base, not the compiled version. Since using `setup` from Numpy library compiles the Fortran code (`from numpy.distutils.core import setup`) during the installing process, we need to install the package in the GitHub workflow. As a result, I added the following line at the end of the `install dependencies` section.

```
pip install -e ../p_name
```

That resolved the issue.